# am i in console app?

Tags: c#, .net, console

is there a way to detect inside the component in C# if the application that uses this component is running in console application or others?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Environment.UserInteractive`. If `true` you are in a console. If `false` you could be in a service.

Comment: `UserInteractive` is `true` for a windowed app, not just a console app.

Comment: There is no UI on a console.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this example for your solution:
http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2004/08/30/223020.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The information you need is a property of your exe assembly.
If you use a tool such as ildasm.exe to view your assembly's manifest, you can see the .subsystem property that indicates the type of execution environment that launches your Main method.

However, it seems like Reflection doesn't expose this info directly.

The code in the following link contains an example for how to read the .exe file itself and detect this infromation:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kstanton/archive/2004/03/31/105060.aspx

I hope this helped.

Comment: cheers Ran, but i would like my code in the library to detected if the process which invoked this library was running in console mode. but thanks for the link anyway, sure it'll come handy at some point.

Comment: This method should still work. You can use Assembly.GetEntryAssembly (or something like that, I don't remember the exact name), and then use Assembly.Location to find the .exe file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is one of the first places I would look -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx

Q: How "sure" do you need to be?

Comment: -1, How could that *possibly* tell you whether your code was running in a console app?